# Simple C++ Logging

Tags: c++, class, debugging, logging

I have been set the task of:

To evolve a Logger class that can be integrated into your
projects/developments, most probably by declaring a single global instance; this will be used to capture and save log information.

There are 2 levels that are acceptable:

1. Logger - essentially just debug code in the
   source, no class.
2. Logger - packaged in a class, with default behavior (not configurable).  Controlled by _DEBUG and writes to `std::clog` (can be re-directed).

I really do not know where to start with this, and have spent hours trying to find help somewhere.

Comment: Why not use some already existing open source library like log4cpp? At least you could learn something from their implementation.

Comment: I think your question must be clearer. If you want to debug you can pass data to ```std::cerr``` and exit or set a breakpoint. You can redirect your messages to a file. What do you mean with "no class" in the first point. Must the logger be classless or do you have code where classes never appear? I would create a Singleton Class named Logger for example and let process everything there. Those are very handy and I use them in my projects, with different log verbosity levels.

Comment: I have copied and pasted my intructions above. This is the only help I have got. This is why I am unsure.

Answer (score 0):

Your task may be to use a more complex Logger class which makes logging throughout your entire project easier due to functionalities such as

- being able to break a string on multiple lines of code when debugging it
- separate methods between error logging and debug logging
- being able to turn logging on/off from that Logger instance, so that all the debug messages throughout your project become obsolete (instead of needing to comment all of them for instance)
- adding other methods specific to your case (you will see below)

This is a Logger class I used for a windows project. It supports all the features previously mentioned. Feel free to use it.

```
#include "Logger.h"

Logger::Logger(
    wstring wstrComponentName,
    wstring wstrFunctionName) :
    _wstrApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME),
    _wstrComponentName(StripFileName(wstrComponentName)),
    _wstrFunctionName(wstrFunctionName)
{}

// This function doesn't support string, but wstring for it's arguments
VOID
Logger::Debug(
    LPCWSTR format,
    ...
    )
{
    wstring wstrBase = 
        _wstrApplicationName + wstring(L": ") +
        _wstrComponentName + wstring(L": ") +
        _wstrFunctionName + wstring(L": ");

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    wchar_t* msg = new wchar_t[_1kB];
    wvsprintf(msg, format, args);

    va_end(args);

    wstring wstrOutput = wstrBase + msg;

    delete[] msg;

    OutputDebugString(wstrOutput.c_str());
}

// This function doesn't support string, but wstring for it's arguments
VOID
Logger::Error(
    LPCWSTR format,
    ...
    )
{
    wstring wstrBase = wstring(L"[ERROR] ") +
        _wstrApplicationName + wstring(L": ") +
        _wstrComponentName + wstring(L": ") +
        _wstrFunctionName + wstring(L": ");

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    wchar_t* msg = new wchar_t[_1kB];
    wvsprintf(msg, format, args);

    va_end(args);

    wstring wstrOutput = wstrBase + msg;

    delete[] msg;

    OutputDebugString(wstrOutput.c_str());
}

wstring
Logger::StripFileName(
    __in wstring wstrFileName
    )
{
    DWORD dwLeftLimit = 0;
    DWORD dwRightLimit = wstrFileName.length();
    wstring wstrResult(L"FileName unavailable");

    if (wstrFileName.rfind(L"\\") != wstring::npos)
    {
        dwLeftLimit = wstrFileName.rfind(L"\\") + 1;
    }

    if (wstrFileName.rfind(L".") != wstring::npos)
    {
        dwRightLimit = wstrFileName.rfind(L".");
    }

    if (dwRightLimit > dwLeftLimit)
    {
        wstrResult = wstrFileName.substr(
            dwLeftLimit,
            dwRightLimit - dwLeftLimit
            );
    }

    return wstrResult;
}
```

Comment: The function ```wvsprintf``` is not very C++ and I would make this ```msg``` variable static so you avoid many allocations and deallocations.